# Upload documents to sharepoint with SPServices

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document-library, jquery, spservices

How can i upload a document to document library in SharePoint Online using `SPServices and JavaScript` (Without using web parts)?

I don't want to use any web services for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using **REST** & **SOAP** web services but if you want to do it using **SPServices** check out [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6733612f-d134-4054-852f-0246bdf6dbbd/how-to-upload-file-in-document-library-using-spservicesjavascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion but i need to use spservices not the web services.

Comment: SPServices is nothing but a wrapper around SharePoints Web Services

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes, but i need to upload documents to the document library.. do you have any better option rather than web services?

Comment: whether SOAP or REST, if you say you want to access SharePoint without using any web service, you are asking to enter the house without opening any door, window (or breaking down a wall). You have to ask your question then on the Penn and Teller (famous american magicians) Forum

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman ,  If you cannot provide a suggestion(Which matches the question) please at least do not waste your time by commenting here. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, I know I am a dickhead sometimes expressing in too many words what could have been answered with "What you are asking can not be done"